# Using SVD to write the least squares fitted vector

Tags: regression, svd

[Elements of statistics p.66](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)

Please I know the least squares solution for $\hat\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ but I don't know how they were able to get

$X\hat\beta= X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = UU^Ty$

These are the steps I followed :

$X\hat\beta = U\sum V^T(V\sum^T U^TU\sum V^T)^{-1}V\sum^T U^Ty \quad (1)$

$X\hat\beta = U\sum V^TV\sum^T U^Ty \quad(2)$

$X\hat\beta = UU^Ty \quad(3)$

Please from $(1)$ , why is $U^TU = I$ and $UU^Ty \neq I$?

Comment: I might have misrepresented the question in my answer. Are you asking why are $U$ columns orthogonal?

Comment: @Firebug I am asking why $U^TU = I$ and  $UU^T \neq I$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the the definition of SVD, $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices. So the products $U^TU$, $V^TV$ are identity matrices.

\begin{cases}
X = USV^T\\
X\hat\beta = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
\end{cases}

So

$$X\hat\beta = (USV^T)((USV^T)^T(USV^T))^{-1}(USV^T)^Ty\\
=USV^T(VS\color{red}{U^TU}SV^T)^{-1}VSU^Ty\\
=USV^T(VS^2V^T)^{-1}VSU^Ty\\
=US\color{red}{V^TV}S^{-2}\color{red}{V^TV}SU^Ty\\
=U\color{red}{SS^{-2}S}U^Ty\\
=UU^Ty\\$$

---

On why $UU^T$ is not necessarily $\mathbb I$, this stems from the definition of the SVD.
A compelling argument can be given by the last line of our derivation, though: $X\hat\beta$ is not necessarily equal to $y$, thus $UU^T$ is not necessarily the identity matrix.

Comment: from your steps (3) why is $ (VS^2V^T)^{-1} = VS^{-2}V^T $ but not $V^{-1}S^{-2}V^{-T}$

Comment: @EALehn that's a property of $V$, $V^T=V^{-1}$. The SVD is often used to calculate matrix powers, like $X^n = US^nV^T$

Comment: so $(VS^2V^T)^{-1} = V^TS^{-1}V$ is also correct or

Comment: @EALehn No, it's not: $(VS^2V^T)^{-1} = (V^{-T}S^{-2}V^{-1}) = VS^{-2}V^T$